# Database Backup compression

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup, compression

I am trying to see all of my backups are compressed or not. I ran below query to check but not getting good result:

```
select top(10) database_name, 
case when  backup_size = compressed_backup_size then 'Compressed'
else 'Not compressed'
end as Compression, 
backup_finish_date
from msdb.dbo.backupset
where database_name ='MyDAtabase'
order by backup_start_date desc
```

I am using:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64)
>   Jun 28 2012 08:36:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>   Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

By default we setup compression, but once I ran that query I got result database is not compressed.

Comment: Backup compression is supported in 2008 R2 standard edition as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.105).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your case statement is wrong. Right now if the values are the same then it shows compressed whereas you would want it to show not compressed.

```
select top(10) database_name, 
case when  backup_size = compressed_backup_size then 'Not compressed'
else 'Compressed'
end as Compression, 
backup_finish_date
from msdb.dbo.backupset
where database_name ='MyDAtabase'
order by backup_start_date desc
```